# Does wxpython run on separate process and release the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock)?

Tags: wxpython

I was wondering the interaction that wxPython has with running things on separate cores and if wxPython releases the GIL when running.

I've assumed that when I kick off some command which takes a while that `wxPython` starts up the `wxWidgets` c++ code which runs on `multiple cores` and somehow `releases the GIL` until the task is finished and then comes back. However I have nothing to base this on. Does this ever happen?

What is actually going on under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GIL is automatically released and reacquired whenever a call is made to a wx C++ function or method.  This is probably a bit of overkill as there are a number of things that are quick and won't ever block and it might be more efficient to not release/reacquire the GIL, but this approach ensures that we don't miss doing it for something that will block.

In addition, any time there is an event dispatched to a Python event handler, or when a virtual method overridden in Python is called, or etc. then the GIL is acquired before entry to that code and released again afterwards.

Comment: So if there is a custom `PostEvent` which is bound to function `def Foo`, and Foo has other wx calls in it, then will the GIL be acquired for the entirety of processing `Foo`,  or would it be released when making those wx calls which are inside of `Foo`?

Comment: It is released and reacquired for every Python --> C++ transition (wrapped wxWidgets functions/methods.) It is acquired and released for every C++ --> Python transition (callbacks, event handlers, overridden virtual methods, etc.)